# where i can get the ms dos alone

Tags: ms-dos

where i can get the ms dos alone ???

Comment: Please add some more detail about your goals here. Your question is quite vague as it is written now. I suspect it will be closed without additional information.

Comment: Wait for it to walk into an alley?

Comment: Get some buddies to go dance with its friends?

Answer (score 5):

[Right here, baby.](http://cgi.ebay.com/MS-Dos-6-22-full-OEM-New-3-5-version-Sealed-/300390674317?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item45f0adef8d) EBay has people selling all kinds of old media. MS-DOS 6.22 is where it's ***at.***

Comment: But that version isn't on a 5.25"!

Comment: 69 bucks!  That's extortionate.

Comment: Too bad I threw out all my shrinkwrapped MS-DOS, PC-DOS, Windows for Workgroups, and Netware floppies. Almost as mad as when I sold all my old Star Wars in a yard sale - if I had kept it for 10 more years I could have made a killing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are using it for,a TechNet subscription Might be a good place to start.  Their catalog goes all the way back into DOS 6.2

Answer (score 0):

There are many different versions of DOS, I think the final version was 8.0. I'm not sure if you still have to pay (probably would only be a couple of £/$) Take a look at [FreeDos](http://www.freedos.org/)